# PHPQuery: получить содержание второго HTML-элемента

Tags: запрос, php

Всем привет.

Есть такой код:

```
    foreach($html->find('#details') as $value) {
        $result['discription'] = pq(pq($value)->find('tbody > tr > td'))->html(); 
    }
```

Вопрос: как получить содержание второго по счету td-элемента, который находится в 'tr'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю что как-то так

```
pq($value)->find('tbody > tr > td:eq(2)');
```

Comment: @Kison, спасибо, но, уже пробовал.

  foreach($html->find('#details') as $value) {
   $result['discription'] = pq(pq($value)->find('tbody > tr > td:eq(1)'))->html(); 
  }
Не работает. Самое странное, что eq(0) видит.

Структура HTML: http://i.imgur.com/T9Dm5TW.png

Comment: Можно еще так попробовать pq($value)->find('tbody > tr > td')[index]

Comment: @Kison, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Код (рабочий) на Simple HTML DOM выглядел так: $value->children(0)->children(1)->outertext;

Здесь же вообще не понимаю, почему не работает ;(

Comment: Может там только один td ?

Comment: @Kison, прикрепил скриншот структуры выше, как быть?

Comment: Все, понятно, проблему решил. tbody просто не существует в исходном коде, но показывается в "исследовании элемента".