# Как заменить содержимое тэга Php

Tags: php

Есть простая html страница, как можно заменить в ней  текстовое содержимое тэгов по условию через php? К примеру заменить в 5 по счету тэге span значение на "привет"

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы что-то поменять в HTML со стороны PHP воспользуйтесь HTML-парсером. Например [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) или [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpquery/)

См. также:

1. [PHPQuery: получить содержание второго HTML-элемента](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/255677/phpquery-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-html-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0)
2. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/354378/177613
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Для полноты вашему ответу не хватает примера кода)